# Add shipping state to subject in WooCommerce new order email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I've already succeeded in finding a way to change the subject of the WooCommerce new order email notification. The problem I'm facing is that the object `$order` doesn't process the `shipping_state` of the user profile.

Here is the code:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);

function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $subject = sprintf( 'Commande pour  %s', $order->shipping_state);

    return $subject;
}
```

I tried calling it directly from the user metadata, but it doesn't work, where it should appear the data, it appears blank.

Here is the code I tried:

```php
function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $user) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $user = wp_get_current_user();  $current_user_id = 
    $user -> ID;

    $user_billing_state = get_user_meta($current_user_id, 'shipping_state', true); 

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $subject = sprintf( 'Commande pour  %s', 
    $user_billing_state);

    return $subject;
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a possibly related question that already [has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63490074/156590), it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code attempt(s) contain some mistakes:

- `$order->shipping_state` is no longer applicable since WooCommerce 3 and has been replaced by `$order->get_shipping_state()`
- The use of `global $woocommerce;` is not necessary
- You use `$blogname`, but you don't do anything with this data, for example you don't display it in the subject

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_subject_new_order( $subject, $order ) {
    // Get shipping state
    $shipping_state = $order->get_shipping_state();
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty( $shipping_state ) ) {
        // Get blogname
        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES );
    
        // Change subject
        $subject = sprintf( __( '%s: Commande pour %s', 'woocommerce' ), $blogname, $shipping_state );
    }

    return $subject;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'filter_woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 10, 2 );
```